# Changing measures from counting measure to Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a Lebesgue measurable space $([0,1], F, \lambda)$, countable measure $\mu$ and a Riemann-integrable function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R (\in L^2([0,1]))$. Define $A_n = \{\frac{i}{2^n} | 0\leq i \leq 2^n\}$. Then,

$$
\int_0^1 fd\lambda = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} f(k)\frac{1}{2^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{A_n} f(k)\frac{1}{2^n} d\mu(A_n)
$$
where the first equality is from the definition of Riemann integration. My question is that can we find some a infinite set such that
$$
\int_0^1 f d\lambda = \int_{A_\infty} g(k) d\mu(A_\infty) = \sum_k^\infty g(k).
$$
My inutition says $g(k) = f'(k)$. So, $f'$ should decay fast at $1$.

I know my question is not rigorous and very vague.. Could you clarify what I am talking about?

Comment: How does Riemann integration come into the picture? Lebesgue integrable functions need not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy OK. Let's restrict ourselves to Riemann integral functions.

Comment: I don't think there are any grounds, not even intuitive ones, for expecting an object like $g$ to have anything to do with $f'$. The integrand in your counting measure integral, $f(x)2^{-n}$, has nothing to do with the derivative of $f$. It has something to do with the derivative of $F=\int f$. So you might expect $g$ to be $F'$, i.e., $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your expectation that $g$ might be $f'$ is misplaced, and you are really getting confused between $f$ and its integral. Remember that when you express the integral of $f$ as a Riemann sum, the terms in the sum don't in any way represent the derivative of $f$, rather by the fundamental theorem of calculus they represent the derivative of the integral of $f$, i.e. $f$ itself.

The integral of $f$ on $[0, 1]$ can be better and better approximated by the sum of $f$ on an "increasingly dense" finite set of points, weighted by $\frac1{2^n}$. With the above caveat on the confusion between $f$ and $f'$, you seem to be asking if there's a way to "take the limit", and express $\int f$ as a sum of $f$ over infinitely many, perhaps dense in $[0, 1]$, points, perhaps also weighted by some value or values.

If this were possible in a way that captured your intuition, presumably it should work on every interval. That is, we should have

$$\int_I f \text dx = \int_I g \text d\mu(A_\infty)$$

where $g$ is maybe $f$ times some weight function, or maybe something more exotic. But in any case this identity should hold for any $I$. Maybe $A_{\infty}$ is a dense set, maybe even the dyadic fractions, which are in some sense the limit of the sequence of point-sets used in your Riemann sums.

But this can't work. Take $I_n$, a nested sequence of intervals with lengths going to zero containing some point $x\in A_\infty$. Then the counting measure integrals should be converging to $g(x)$, but the standard integrals should be converging to $0$, since the intervals are going to zero in length.

The trouble in my view is that you're ignoring that $\frac1{2^n}$ in the Riemann sums. No reasonable "at infinity" version of that counting measure integral could be anything other than zero.